Как нарисовать объект с круглыми отверстиями в SFML?
Я создаю простейшую систему 2D освещения — рисую поверх всех игровых объектов черный полупрозрачный прямоугольник, за исключением освещаемых мест. Каждый источник света содержит радиус и координаты центра окружности, которую он освещает. Соответственно, мне нужно нарисовать sf::RectangleShape с отверстиями, заданными sf::CircleShape. Как это сделать с адекватной производительностью?

Создать текстуру размером с экран, залить черным цветом, нарисовать в ней белые круги там где нужно. Потом всю эту текстуру нарисовать во весь экран, выставив режим смешивания цвета в "умножить".
